# ImageResizer/System.Drawing and CMYK JPEGs

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing, imageresizer

I'm doing some simple image resizing and rotation in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project, using the ImageResizer library. The problem is that when I use it to process 32-bpp CMYK JPEG files, it fails with an ArgumentException, but only on my (Windows Server 2008 R2) server - it works fine on my (Windows Vista) laptop.

The JPEG files in question aren't too large (700x500) or otherwise non-standard - all web browsers and Paint can open them just fine, even on the server in question itself. The JPEGs have been generated using ImageMagick, and everything works fine if I ask ImageMagick to use an RGB colorspace (`-colorspace sRGB`.)

The weird thing is, just resizing the image works fine in all cases, but it fails if I try to resize and rotate the image on the server.

It looks like some lower-level Win32 or GDI+ function call is what's failing here - here's the relevant part of the stack trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.]
   System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status) +1621285
   System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, PointF[] destPoints, RectangleF srcRect, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttr, DrawImageAbort callback, Int32 callbackData) +727
   System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, PointF[] destPoints, RectangleF srcRect, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttr) +73
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.RenderImage(ImageState s) +763
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Render(ImageState s) +174
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Process(ImageState s) +105
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.buildToBitmap(Bitmap source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean transparencySupported) +276
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.buildToStream(Bitmap source, Stream dest, ResizeSettings settings) +149
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJob(ImageJob job) +940
   ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job) +223
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you using 'rotate' or 'srotate'? GDI uses WIC internally on WS2008 R2, and seems to be loading CMYK data, but can't actually support rotate operations on it, it seems. `rotate` should work even if `srotate` (source rotate) does not.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist I was using srotate -- my app needed to rotate the image first, then crop it.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist I guess this is exactly the reason why libraries like ImageResizer exist -- to abstract away these weird bugs and quirks. Maybe you can consider updating it to handle this case.

Comment: It's absolutely on the TODO list; in fact, I'd tested for it, but forgot to test 'srotate' as well as 'rotate'. If you're on GitHub, you can even submit a patch to speed things along.

Comment: This bug was fixed in version 3.3.1.

Comment: I've started encountering the same bug using 4.0.0.0. Remove the `autorotate=true` option from my call to `ImageBuilder.Current.Build()`'s `ResizeSettings` parameter, and my app works. Leave it in there, and it throws the ArgumentException. The images I'm working with aren't altered by ImageMagick or anything; they're just plain ol' iOS photos. http://pastebin.com/EwU2CUPh

Comment: Notably, I was also trying to convert the format to png. If I remove that, the code stops crashing as well. So maybe it's the specific combination of the autorotate + format options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and testing, I've found that the problem occurs only if the `Bitmap.RotateFlip` method has been called on the source bitmap, before it is drawn onto a target bitmap for cropping and resizing.

I ended up having to re-write the code using plain old `System.Drawing` myself, because there is no way to change the behavior of the ImageResizer library. Specifically, I wrote my own rotation function, which uses a transformation matrix to do the same thing.

```
    private Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle)
    {
        if (angle == 0) return (Bitmap)source.Clone();

        Bitmap target;
        using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        using (Matrix matrix = new Matrix())
        {
            path.AddRectangle(new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, source.Width, source.Height));
            matrix.Rotate(angle);
            RectangleF rect = path.GetBounds(matrix);

            target = new Bitmap((int)Math.Round(rect.Width), (int)Math.Round(rect.Height));
            target.SetResolution(source.HorizontalResolution, source.VerticalResolution);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
            {
                g.TranslateTransform(-rect.X, -rect.Y);
                g.RotateTransform(angle);
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(source, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
```

I would have wanted to set the `PixelFormat` of the new `Bitmap` to the one from the source - but doing so throws weird GDI+ "Out of memory" errors on encountering the CMYK JPEG files in question. This makes me wonder if this odd behavior is linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4315335/1292105) GDI+ bug/quirk that returns different `ImageFlags` and `PixelFormat` values on Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 and Windows Vista/Server 2008.