# C# - fast byte array to bitmap conversion with Graphics to add text

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, arrays, marshalling

I'm converting byte[] to bitmap using this function:

```
public static Bitmap ArrayToBitmap(
    byte[] bytes, int width, int height, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
    {
        var image = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
        var imageData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                          ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pixelFormat);
        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, imageData.Scan0, bytes.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            image.UnlockBits(imageData);
        }
        return image;
    }
```

this works great. If I convert the result back to byte[] and output it as ByteArrayContent I see the resulting image in the browser. My source file is a PNG and for pixelFormat parameter I can use either Format16bppArgb1555 or Format32bppArgb, both work if I convert back from bitmap to byte[].

However when I'm trying to feed the converted bitmap into:

```
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    // add custom text to image
}
```

For Format16bppArgb1555 I get an "out of memory" exception on the "using" line when it tries to create Graphics object using .FromImage(). The exception reads:

```
Message = "Out of memory."
Source = "System.Drawing"
```

and for Format32bppArgb the result is a corrupted image with my custom text on top of it.

Is it possible to get one of them to work? Alternatively, is there a fast way of converting byte[] to image, adding text and converting result back to byte[] again?

I tried using Magick.NET (Q8-x64) which enabled me to do all of the above only it was really slow. Slower than the regular method:

1. convert byte[] to MemoryStream
2. get bitmap from Image.FromStream()
3. add text
4. bitmap.Save() to MemoryStream
5. memoryStream.ToArray()

Edit 2:
probably worth to mention that the original PNG images comes from HTML5 Canvas .[ToDataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)() method.

Comment: So the exceptions happen in `// add custom text to image` ? Can we see that then?

Comment: the exception is thrown on Graphics.FromImage(bitmap), before it can reach the "add custom text to image". I updated my question with this info.

Comment: that outOfMemoryException is rather delicately explained in the upvoted answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723855/outofmemoryexception-out-of-memory-system-drawing-graphics-fromimage). I personally use WriteableBitmap class with WriteableBitmapEx extension. You might want to look into that.

Comment: Thanks @pijemcolu, I tried your method with WriteableBitmap and ext:

    var wb = BitmapFactory.New(h, w).FromByteArray(image);
            wb.Lock();
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, wb.BackBufferStride, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, wb.BackBuffer);

if I output bitmap right here, it comes out corrupted just like in my example in original question